# Qual è il significato di "pigliarcene" in questo passaggio?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nella prefazione a *Nostro lunedí* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> Ci scrivevano divertentissime lettere: nelle prime sei righe ci facevano chiaramente capire che noi potevamo con tutta tranquillità porre la nostra candidatura fra i grandi del secolo: nelle ultime due si rammaricavano che la difficoltà del momento li costringesse a rifiutare l’offerta. Incolpavano il pubblico, eccetera. Soprattutto, si preoccupavano di mostrare a nostro favore una specie di sdegno civile. Facemmo male a **pigliarcene**: quelle lettere erano degne di noi.

Ho cercato il verbo "pigliare" in parecchi dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "pigliarcene" in questo passaggio. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Secondo me nel senso di "prendercela" o "rimanerci male" (vedi http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/prendere/ par. 14)

Comment: Concordo con Riccardo De Contardi: il significato è proprio quello di «prendersela», con sostituzione del verbo non marcato («prendere») con un verbo marcato (almeno diatopicamente, oggi).

Comment: @FerdinandBardamu: Potresti scrivere una risposta?

Comment: Oltre a usare un verbo diverso da quello più usuale (almeno attualmente), è diversa anche la reggenza: “pigliarce_ne_” anziché “pigliarce_la_”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Pigliarsela* è una forma alternativa, con sostituzione sinonimica, di *prendersela*. Il significato è affine a *impermalirsi*, *aversela* (o *aversene*) *a male*.

In questo caso, come è stato detto nei commenti, rispetto a un’ipotetica forma base *prendersela*, cambia anche uno dei due clitici: da *la* a *ne*. Il significato, però, rimane lo stesso.

*Pigliarsela* e *pigliarsene* sono semanticamente equivalenti, dunque, ma il secondo è senza dubbio piú raro del primo. Lo dimostrano le sparute attestazioni che si possono trovare in Rete. Tra queste, cito:

[Platone, *Critone*, traduzione di Francesco Acri](https://it.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Critone/Capitolo_XIV)

> Ancora in quel che si faceva il giudizio, t’era lecito per penitenza prendere da te lo andare in esilio; e ciò che ti disponi ora a fare a dispetto della città, potevi fare tu allora col suo consentimento. Ma allora ti facevi bello dando vista di non **pigliartene** all’idea che bisognasse morire; anzi dicevi meglio voler la morte, che l’esilio[.]

[Aristofane, *Le vespe*, traduzione di Ettore Romagnoli](http://www.filosofico.net/aristofvespe42.htm)

> FILOCLEONE (Con voce rotta e fioca):  
>   Dimmelo... davvero... 
>   è prosciolto?  
>   SCHIFACLEONE:    
>   Perdio!  
>   FILOCLEONE:
>   Sono finito!    
>   (Ricasca giú)  
>   SCHIFACLEONE: 
>   Sta su, benedett'uomo, non **pigliartene**!  
>   FILOCLEONE (Cupo e tragico):   
>   Come sopporterò tanto rimorso?
>   Prosciolsi un imputato. Or che mi resta?
>   Deh, venerandi Numi, perdonatemi!
>   Non è da me, ma non l'ho fatto apposta!

*Pigliarsela*, *pigliarsene*, *prendersela*, ecc. sono verbi procomplementari, in cui «altri pronomi clitici [oltre a *si*] (*ci*, *la*, *le*, *ne*) si saldano al verbo» (Enciclopedia dell’Italiano, «[Verbi pronominali](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-pronominali_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/)»).

Comment: A orecchio suona verosimile, ma mi sentirei più sicuro se vedessi qualche altro esempio in cui “pigliarcene” è usato in questo senso.

Comment: @DaG [Qui](https://goo.gl/9to2RY) c’è un altro esempio, basta cercare nella pagina «non pigliartene». Un altro esempio si trova [qui](https://goo.gl/a69Qb2), sempre nella forma «non pigliartene». In generale, pare che il verbo procomplementare «pigliarsene» sottintenda «cura, pensiero, briga e sim.».

Comment: @FerdinandBardamu: La citazione del *Critone* di Platone appare anche nella [Wikisource](https://it.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Critone/Capitolo_XIV). Si tratta di una traduzione di Francesco Acri pubblicata da Vallecchi nel 1925. Penso sia interessante includere questi due esempi (traduzioni di Francesco Acri e di Ettore Romagnoli) nella risposta: così sarà più ben argomentata.

Comment: @Charo: grazie del suggerimento. Ho aggiunto gli esempi alla risposta.